# Can't log in to the Stack Exchange app with a Google account

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login

I tried logging in with a Google account, but I got the following error:

[image: screenshot of detailed code: 400 error]

Comment: From the error message, I think this is a [tag:bug].

Comment: I have the same problem. Running iOS. Hasn't worked for 2 days.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/376216/1338846 (iOS)

Comment: I've been experiencing this bug for more than 2 weeks and they have no solution so far.

Comment: Why? Why I did logout from app? Will never logout from iOS app at least.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa there is nobody that can fix it. The only android developer SE ever hired (Kasra) no longer works for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog because it actually made the image _too_ small for mobile users

Comment: @ShadowWizard I forgot I had an OpenID associated to this account, but still it's strange we this bug popped up without the app being updated. Even more strange is the fact SE is lacking programmers lol.

Comment: @EzequielBarbosa nothing strange... SE made a business decision to ditch the apps in favor of working on other things. I'm only surprised they let the apps slowly decay and fall apart rather than just shutting them down. This cause hundreds of people who still use the apps to get frustrated.

Comment: In theory they still do bug fixes. In practice I don't know. And until SE gets web notifications, this is still the only way to get notifications on mobile

Comment: Same problem here. I got new android phone and now I can't login on the app anymore.

Comment: @animuson Would you mind posting an answer explaining what the issue was?

Comment: @Sonic it's no less than a miracle they fixed it; Expecting details is really way too much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed as of 1 Dec 2018, re download the app if still experiencing problems based on my experience.

EDIT:
Earliest fix was apparently 29 Nov 2018

Comment: According to SE staff it was fixed before December 1. (Nov 29)